# Estimate the population proportion at $99\%$ confidence, based on a sample of $300$ people

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I believe the following problem should be solved using the student distribution. Do I have that right? Is my solution correct?

Problem:

In an organization of $1000$ employees, a survey was made using a random
sample of $300$ people regarding prohibiting smoking in the parking lots
of the organization buildings. $210$ people agree to prohibit-smoking in
the parking lots of the organization.  Estimate the population proportion
that would agree to prohibit smoking in the parking lots of the
origination buildings at $99\%$ confidence.

Answer:

To solve this problem, I use the Student T distribution.
\begin{eqnarray*}
n &=& 300 \\
\overline{x} &=& 210 \\
u &=& \frac{210*10}{3} = \frac{2100}{3} = 700 \\
\overline{x} &=& 210 \\
df &=& n - 1 = 300 - 1 = 299 \\
s &=& \sqrt{ npq } = \sqrt{ 300(\frac{7}{10})(\frac{3}{10})} \\
s &=& \sqrt{ 3(7)(10)} = 14.491 \\
SE( \overline{x} ) &=& \frac{s}{\sqrt{ \pi } } =
    \frac{14.491}{\sqrt{ 3.1415926 } }  = 8.1756713 \\
CI &=& u \pm (t*)(SE( \overline{x}) ) \\
t* &=& 2.35 \\
CI &=& 700 \pm (2.35)(8.1756713) =
    700 \pm (2.35)(8.1756713) = 700 \pm 19.212 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You're asked to build a C.I. for "proportion" not "mean". Use point estimate of proportion along with standard normal distribution instead of t. And usually we've to apply a correction factor when dealing with finite population (which is the case here).

Comment: This is helpful http://canmedia.mheducation.ca/college/olcsupport/bowerman/2ce/OptionalContent/bow02371_OLC_7_9.pdf

Comment: I do not understand this comment: You're asked to build a C.I. for "proportion" not "mean". Are you saying that I did it all wrong? My understanding is that you use the t distribution when the population standard deviation is not known which is the case here.

Comment: "My understanding is that you use ...." Yes you're correct but that's when building C.I. for "Population Mean". Here we've to build C.I. for "Population proportion". Proportion is always between 0 and 1. Read the PDF file in the link provided above. That should clear your doubt.